# How to timeout current running API call without using any extra threads?

Tags: java, java-8, timeout, threadpool, future

I have been looking for answer to this from one week, couldn't find anything relatable. Finally decided to post here.

I have use-case, where I need to give custom timeouts to different API calls. This use-case sounds very common. right ? well, I want to achieve this without using any extra threads. I am looking for system-clock described as given below.

So basically, I want to write one method ( calling it, `EnforceTimeout()` ), This method takes callable ( API call converted into callable format, which returns `response`, or `exception` ), and timeout in Miliseconds.

```
public static Object EnforceTimeout(Callable callable, Long TimeoutInMS) throws exceptions {

    // Do Some Steps on current thread, but not create new thread/thread-pool
    // 1. Start the clock 

    // 2. Make API call

    // 3. Clock runs in background which takes care of the timeout, and if API call exceeds the time-limit then automatically enforce the exception.
       
}
```

Now, Some of you might have doubt, how can we keep track of elapsed time, without creating new thread. So here, let me describe a strategy like an Event-loop( in JavaScript ). We can define a system-clock. This clock should be able to look after 10 to 100 such callable's timeouts. It can check on such callable on priority queue (whichever callable has closest ending time), whether we have crossed the time limit.

Your next argument would be, one such system-clock instance would be inefficient to manage large number of callables. In that case, We need system-clock-manager, which will manage, how many such a clocks we will need, it should be able to handle the scaling of such system clock instances.

Please, let me know, if anything as such possible in java. If my question/idea is duplicate, pls guide me to the discussion, where I can find more information about the same. Thank you very much.

Comment: The term “round-robin fashion” makes no sense here. You should use a priority queue to be able to fetch the action whose timeout is the closest. Besides that, this JavaScipt feature you described, matches that of `javax.swing.Timer`, which will execute the `ActionListener`’s code within AWT’s event loop when the time has elapsed. But this is entirely unrelated to your wish to stop or interrupt already running code, which is impossible to do without another thread.

Comment: @Holger  , yes that makes more sense... Lemme update my question... thanks for the suggestion :) .. but yeah,,, still nobody has replied anything as such... so I don't think there is such a library/method to do so... it is good headstart to work on weekends :P